# Is there a way to have conditional fields like in Drupal 7?

Tags: fields

I use CIVI 5.x and Drupal 7.

I would like to have conditional fields, that display is certain conditions are met, for example:

New Customer, IF group is business, show business address field, IF group is individual, show home address, etc..

Same behavior as Drupal conditional fields basically

Comment: It depends, on which page you want to use conditions. If it is something where webform can be used (webform civicrm integration module will provide facility to use civi fields in webform) then you can define conditionals in webform settings. If its a contribution page for example or a profile then you would need to use buildForm hook and will need to do custom coding

Comment: have you considered doing whatever you need via civicrm_webform which then gives you Webform Conditionals to play with

Comment: Yes, I have a lot of experience with webform, but how do I integrate with CIVI Crm? My setup shares the database with D7, running on Xampp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webform with native conditionals fields works great. [SOLVED]

Answer (score 1):

For a Civi-native solution, there's also the [Profile Conditionals](https://github.com/twomice/com.joineryhq.profcond) extension, but it's in a fairly early state.  It's a bit tricky to configure, but works well once you do!