# Adding Sub-Options of Custom Data

Tags: joomla, civicrm-home

Maybe I didn't know, but I didn't know.
I need to add a sub-option to private recipients. I can explain this with an example.

Suppose you have an option. When I make a choice here, there must be sub-options that are optional in this option.

#### Apple

White Apple

Green apple

Red Apple

#### Pear

White Pear

Green Pear

Red Pear

Joomla 3.9.3
CiviCRM 5.10.2

[image]

Comment: There are several similar questions about "conditional fields". See for example https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26018/is-there-a-way-to-have-conditional-fields-like-in-drupal-7

Comment: might be worth checking what civirules can offer you

Comment: I have a client who is potentially interested in funding this exact functionality, but it will likely be a couple of months before we implement it.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know you can not create (sub)options depending on the value of a (top) option in core CiviCRM. So that would mean you would have to develop a little extension that does this?

As far as the county stuff goes, is that an unrelated question? If so can you please make it separate as it will be impossible to find if others experience the same issue.

Comment: Hi Erik,
I couldn't understand what you wanted to say because my English knowledge wasn't very good. If the situation you're talking about is developing a plugin I'm not at the potential to do it.

Comment: It is not possible with standard CiviCRM, you will need to develop an extension (plugin) for this. If you are not able to do that you can check if one of the existing extensions can help you. You can find them on https://civicrm.org/extensions

Answer (score 2):

re: custom data sub options:
You can do that with tags and tag sets, but they would be applicable to all contacts not given sub types

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/groups-and-tags/

It will probably make life easier if you ask the country/ province/ state question on a separate post

Comment: Hey, Craig Almond,

The label does not resolve the problem. There will be a serious data entry, but the list will be a waste of time to search and select. The label can be considered as a last resort.

I made different facilities in the province / district information. Same situation. I will continue by opening a different topic for this.